# Angular 2 able to post request but not able to read the remote resource

Tags: laravel-5, cors, angular2-services

I tried to post a request to my Laravel backend but failed to get the response as the error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/path. (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-origin’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)" showed.

I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers in both my client and server. Why does the error still showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the client-side code you added to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the request.

> (Reason: **missing token ‘access-control-allow-origin’** in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)" showed.
>
> I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers **in both my client** and server. Why does the error still showing?

The error is showing because you added an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the client-side request. But `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a server *response* header. So if you send it from the client side in a request you’ll see the kind of error you’re seeing now.

*“missing token ‘access-control-allow-origin’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’“* is the browser telling you that your client code is  sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` request header, but the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header the server has returned doesn’t list "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" as one of the header names it allows in requests.

So because of that, the browser isn’t letting your frontend JavaScript code read the response.

Comment: After removing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, it shows **Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing** now instead of the earlier error

Comment: Don’t remove `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the `http://localhost:8000/path` server side

Comment: I did not remove it and i found the cause is that the route "oauth/token" of Laravel Passport was not calling the cors middleware that assigned to it but your explanation cleared my confusion bout CORS. Still figuring out how to add the middleware to Passport::route(). I have tried 

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function() { Passport::routes(); }); `

but the middleware still not working.

Comment: OK the answer here is for the original problem you reported in the question. The new problem mentioned in your comment above that you now have (after having fixed the original problem by doing what’s described in the answer here)  is a different problem, which, if you want to get more help with it here, you probably want to post a separate new question for that